# Using ternary for variable assignment

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel I have a controller

It gets a bunch of data and saves it like so

```
        $lastinid = $user->onlineApplications()->create($newInsertData);
```

If payment_status is successfully, i want invoice to be 1, otherwise i want it to be 0. How do I do this using a ternary operator.

```
if($lastinid->payment_status == "success"){
      $invoice = 1;
    }
```

Comment: `$invoice = $lastinid->payment_status == "success" ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the Ternary Operator and view an example at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

For your case:

```
$invoice = ($lastinid->payment_status == "success") ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$invoice = $lastinid->payment_status == "success" ? 1 : 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Using typecasting hint you can even do:

```
$invoice = (int)($lastinid->payment_status == "success");
```

This will work as `true` value is converted to integer `1` and `false` to integer `0`. Of course, this will work for `1/0` only, for all other numbers use ternary.